# Is there a tool to Automate iPhone testing without Jailbreaking it ? (except UI Automation)

Tags: iphone, testing, mobile, automation, functional-testing

Is there a tool to perform functional and regression test on iPhone without jailbreaking it ? 
I have worked with UI Automation (ios4) but it is not extensive. DA, Perfecto are remote and slow, plus too costly.

Squish, Fonemonkey, UISpec needs the app code to be integrated with tool which is again not feasible when i have only the app file. 
So is there a way to sort this out ?

Answer (score 1):

Other options include [Appium](http://appium.io/), [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/), [Frank](http://testingwithfrank.com/), and [Zucchini](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code then you can test it with Xcode Instrumant for all kind of testing.

If you don't have any code then you can use both build file and provisioning certificate to install it in your iPhone device.

For all testing purpose i always prefer device testing rather than depending upon 3rd party tools.